# Как открыть popup magento?

Tags: php, magento, popup

При регистрации пользователя (сразу после регистрации выполняется вход) должно отображаться модальное окно!

Для отслеживания регистрации пользователя я использовал `customer_register_success`

Создал в конфиге:

```
           <events>
                <customer_register_success>
                    <observers>
                        <mymodule_customer_register_success>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>hexbrain_tweaks/customer</class>
                            <method>customerRegisterSuccess</method>
                        </mymodule_customer_register_success>
                    </observers>
                </customer_register_success>
            </events>
```

Создал модель `Customer`, а в ней метод:

```
public function customerRegisterSuccess(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {}
```

Все работает, и при регистрации пользователя - выполняется метод в модели, что я создал!

Но мое модальное окно создается при обращении к действию контроллера (например другое модальное окно создается при нажатии на кнопку при обращении к действию таким образом `onclick="openPopUp('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('mp/mymodal/contact')?>`);

**Как таким образом (например то же действие) можно выполнить при переходе в метод** `customerRegisterSuccess` ?

Буду благодарен за подсказку!

Comment: переформируй вопрос немного не понятно что именно ты хочешь?

Comment: @Naumov, спасибо за отклик ) уже разобрался!